# How to trim text in Win2D using geometry

Tags: windows, win2d

I know Win2D allows you to draw text within a specific rectangle and you can set it so that text not within that rectangle is clipped so that it isn't drawn.

I was wondering if it would be possible to do this with not just a rectangle but any Geometry (which may include curved lines)

What I get with rectangular clipping:

[image]

What I want (clipping by the white rounded rectangle with the curved bottom):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One of the CreateLayer overloads will probably do what you want:

http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/Overload_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasDrawingSession_CreateLayer.htm